# How to disable impact feedback on UIRefreshControl?

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol

Is there any way to disable haptic on `UIRefreshControl`?
Or I need to create custom view?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [associated documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol) there’s not much you can configure. So you will most probably need a custom control.

You can, however, add custom subviews. Please see this: https://www.appcoda.com/custom-pull-to-refresh/ for an example.

Comment: Probably I'll have to use custom view, because custom subviews won't disable haptic.